# Laravel: The save function does not work properly when updating a row with the Postgres database

Tags: php, laravel, database, postgresql, laravel-8

```
$movie = Movie::find(1855613);
$movie->title = 'Ponteng School';
$movie->save();
```

This code not only updates the given ID, It is updates all my rows with the same title. After the disaster, I had to restore the backup of the 10 GB size database. Luckily I had a backup.

I was running the same code on MySQL server it is working fine, but on Postgres server it is not working as I like. I saw the problem was save function then I skipped save function and use update function

`Movie::where("id", 1855613)->update(["title" =>'Ponteng School']);`

- Laravel Version: 8.75
- PHP Version: 8.0
- Database Driver & Version: pgsql & postgres (PostgreSQL) 12.9 (Ubuntu 12.9-0ubuntu0.20.04.1)

Do you have any thoughts about this issue?